# What are the equivalents of the default shader uniforms provided by Three.js in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, glsl

**What I want to achieve:**

I have a fully functional shader for 3D objects written in GLSL, that was initially designed for Three.js, that I would like to use in libGDX now. The full code of the shader and the link to a live preview is provided at the end.

In the shader, I have the following uniforms, that were initially provided by Three.js:

```
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
```

As per [Three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram), the values of the uniforms are the following:

```
// = object.matrixWorld
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

// = camera.matrixWorldInverse * object.matrixWorld
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

// = camera.projectionMatrix
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

// = camera.matrixWorldInverse
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

// = inverse transpose of modelViewMatrix
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

// = camera position in world space
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
```

**My question:**

How do I get these values in libGDX?

```
@Override
    public void render(Renderable renderable) {
        program.setUniformMatrix(modelMatrix, ???);
        program.setUniformMatrix(modelViewMatrix, ???);
        program.setUniformMatrix(projectionMatrix, ???);
        program.setUniformMatrix(viewMatrix, ???);

        renderable.meshPart.render(program);
    }
```

Here is the code of the shader.

**Fragment:**

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;


uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec2 vUv2;

void main() {
    vec3 worldPosition = ( modelMatrix * vec4( vPosition, 1.0 )).xyz;
    vec3 worldNormal = normalize( vec3( modelMatrix * vec4( vNormal, 0.0 ) ) );
    vec3 lightVector = normalize( lightPosition - worldPosition );
    float brightness = dot( worldNormal, lightVector );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color * brightness, 1.0 );
}
```

**Vertex:**

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;
attribute vec2 uv2;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec2 vUv2;

void main() {
    vNormal = normal;
    vUv = uv;
    vUv2 = uv2;
    vPosition = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

**Live preview of the shader:**

https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/5365

Any help is highly appreciated!